# How to automatically identify the start and stop times of a "ramp" seen in time series?

Tags: python, time-series, peak-detection

I am analyzing pressure data sampled at 1Hz. The times series exhibit "ramps" (a linear increase in pressure followed by a sudden drop) for which I would like to automatically detect the start and stop times. Please note that these pressure events are *not* periodic:

[image]

My first attempt was to use SciPy's `find_peaks` function on a smoothed version of my data.

I first smoothed these time series using the function described in [the SciPy's cookbook](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/SignalSmooth.html):

```
smoothed_pressure = smooth(df['Pressure'], window_len=21)
```

[image]

I then applied `find_peaks` to find the maximum peaks (in red) above the `mean_amplitude` of the smoothed data and the minimum peaks (in yellow) below this amplitude:

```
mean_amplitude = np.mean(smoothed_pressure)
max_indices = find_peaks(smoothed_pressure, distance=200, height=mean_amplitude)[0]
min_indices = find_peaks(smoothed_pressure, distance=200, height=[0,mean_amplitude])[0]

plt.figure(figsize=(20,3))
plt.title(filename)
plt.plot(df['Time'], df["Pressure"])
plt.scatter(df[df.index.isin(max_indices-11)]['Time'], df[df.index.isin(max_indices-11)]["Pressure"], color='red', zorder=5)
plt.scatter(df[df.index.isin(min_indices-11)]['Time'], df[df.index.isin(min_indices-11)]["Pressure"], color='yellow', zorder=5)
```

[image]

After tweaking the `distance` I managed to get this strategy to work for this specific example, but this solution is not robust enough and fails when applied to other datasets.

I am looking for other strategies to deal with this problem.

I am thinking of differentiating the data before trying to identify the peaks.
I am also open to trying machine learning strategies.
Any other idea will be welcome!

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**EDIT: IMPLEMENTING MAXTRON'S SOLUTION**

As suggested by Maxtron in his answer below, computing the second order derivative is an excellent way to nail down the stop time of each ramp.

In the example below I apply the second order derivative on a (heavily) smoothed version of the original data:

```
ds=pd.DataFrame()
mylength=61
smoothed_time = smooth(df['Time'], window_len=mylength)
smoothed_pressure = smooth(df['Pressure'], window_len=mylength)
ds['Pressure']=smoothed_pressure
ds['Time']=smoothed_time
```

I then compute the first and second order derivatives of this smoothed signal:

```
ds['Pressure_first_derivative']=ds['Pressure'].diff() / ds['Time'].diff()
ds['Pressure_second_derivative']=ds['Pressure_first_derivative'].diff() / ds['Time'].diff()
```

The second order derivative looks like this:

[image]

Identifying the samples exceeding a user-defined threshold of 0.15 is a good starting point to identify the *end* of each ramp:

```
max_indices=ds[ds['Pressure_second_derivative']>0.15].index-np.int(mylength/2)
```

[image]

There are probably ways to automate the thresholding. Also, because multiple samples exceed this threshold for each peak, I think that `find_peaks` would still be needed to boil down each group of points to a single sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second derivative of a [ramp function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramp_function) is a delta function. So essentially, you can construct a new signal by taking the second derivative of the original signal.

*Approach*: If the original signal $\mathbf{x}$ is given as $x(0), \ldots, x(N-1)$, then the second derivative is given as

\begin{align}
y[t] = x[t] - 2 x[t-1] + x[t-2], \quad 2 \le t < N
\end{align}

The second derivative is sparse at points when the ramp signal ends. You can avoid `find_peaks` function when you use the second derivative signal. Applying a simple thresholding technique should help you find the location of the peaks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will give it a shot!

Comment: I tried implementing the approach that you suggested: I edited my post accordingly. I think that your solution is great to identify the **end** of each ramp, but now I must still find a workaround to identify the **beginning** of each ramp. Also, as stated above, I think that `find_peaks` will still come in handy. Anyways, thanks again for your answer!